# jQuery $.ajax function randomly fails to index.php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form that submits to a function.  The issue is randomly it fails and locks up.  After looking close at firebug it keeps changing my url from functions/changePassword.php to functions/index.php

Current Function

```
function submitchangePasswordForm() {
    showLoading();
    var formData = new FormData($('#changePasswordForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'functions/changePassword.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == '1') {
            popup_alert('Your password has been updated successfully.', 'Update Successful', 'Ok');
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop : 0
            });
            $('#changePasswordForm').each(function () {
                this.reset();
            });
        } else {
            popup_alert('An error occured preventing us from changing your password. <br> Error: <br>' + data, 'Update Failed', 'Ok');
            $('#old_pass').val('');
            $('#changePasswordForm').submit();
        }
        hideLoading();
    });
}
```

Before anyone asks the resubmit on error is used because I am using jQuery validation to show that the field is blank again.

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong to cause the error?

Comment: Why are you resubmitting the form in `$('#changePasswordForm').submit()` ?

Comment: There is a submit prevention system. As I said above all that does is highlight the box and places a comment of this field is required as per the jQuery validation plugin. If removed I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a similar problem although it did not return me to Index, but that could be a .htaccess setting.

The solution was to write my URL as `url : '/directory/page.php'` 
Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Never thought of that. Turns out that one of our coders put in a redirect for any file named changePassword.php for another system. After placing a directory restriction on it everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the `<form onsubmit ..` method? When it fails you're calling `$('#changePasswordForm').submit()` but it's unclear what the `action` attribute is.

If your `<form>` doesn't have an `action='somewhere'` field, it will submit it to the same page. I'm guessing that's probably it.

Comment: if you read the above statement "Before anyone asks the resubmit on error is used because I am using jQuery validation to show that the field is blank again."  The form will not submit as the old_pass field is required and prevents the form from being submitted.  Also it is only submitted.